# Not able to create manifest file .PFA in sitecore jss with next.js

Tags: jss, sitecore-api, nextjs

I am trying to integrate `sitecore-jss` with `next.js`, when I am trying to run the below command '`jss deploy app --accept certificate 426a2098ef89941dec9f277a4bc1ef677f555a4a -c -d`'
getting not able to create `manifest file .PFA`

[image: manifest error]